# How do I replace the king stud and header on a termite damage exterior wall?

Tags: walls, doors, studs, frame, termite

[image: HighlightedDamageArea][image: exteriorwall]

Exterior wall has termite damage and I'm not sure how to support it and replace it.

Comment: Which king stud? We can't see what you're looking at without some pics or drawings, so anything we might say would be nothing more than a well intentioned but blind guess. Please [edit] to include some pics of the actual damage, if you can, and a sketch or two showing the joists above & below the area in question. Also, it's important to know what's below this area - accessible basement, crawlspace, 1st floor, what?

Comment: I uploaded a pic. Its one story duplex on concrete slab with 10 ft ceilings and the attic has probably 10-15 foot  rafters at its peak. Joists run parallel to the back door wall and window, which is where the termite damage is.

Comment: The left or right really doesn’t matter I think I see a seam or sub floor what’s under there is important, worst case lay a 2x 6 on the floor 16” away from the wall, then a 2x6 at the ceiling, on the left wall wedge a 2x 4 or 6 in 4 places starting on the wall and moving out. Now the damaged king and cripples can be removed after that the other uprights. After the damaged wood is replaced and treated the temp support can be removed

Comment: What type of siding do you have? If it can be removed it would certainly help refastening the new framing to the sheathing. That's pretty important.

Comment: Vinyl siding outside,  laminate planks flooring (except by the door,  there is ceramic tile),  left side of the duplex back door with ceiling joists running parallel to the damaged wall.